# Fit a picture to an area automatically

Tags: adobe-photoshop, image-editing

I am trying to fit a picture (two pictures, actually) to a predefined area so I do not have to do it manually every time.

More specifically I want to place a given cover and disc image onto a frame to look like the following:

[image: example]

I did it using a frame, however when I go to add a new image, every time I have to resize to different measurements to get it to fit in the framed areas.

Comment: Please share what you have tried and why it is failing.

Comment: so your final result is, as the image you posted, tilted and includes the part outside of the black part?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add more details, your own attempts, etc. Take the [tour] to learn how the site works.

Comment: Have you tried using [Smart Objects?](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/create-smart-objects.html)

Comment: Havent tried smart objects. Have solved the comming out of the frame issue. The only issue now is the image size. When i add a cover with dimesion to fit, i may have to alter the image to say 100 0by 1000 pixels and it fits snug. The nest image i place in theory should be the same, however when i alter the dimension of it to the same 1000 by 1000 it is to small or to big and have to mess with it sometimes making it 3 or 4 times large / smller. its weird

Comment: ***Thanks everyone for input, have solved it. I was not altering the resolution of the images and this was the cause of the issue..
THANKS***